# The cronjob is not running

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I have a local machine(Mac Mini) where i want a Python script to run every day between a specific time interval.I have created a crontab and added the commands for the execution but seems it is not running at all, Didn't find  way to check whether it is running and what is the issue that is causing it not to run.

The python script is using selenium to do a web-search and opens a chrome browser but it is not opening at all, so i think the cron is not running or how can we monitor the status.

Below is the output of "crontab -l" (*Want this Python script to execute every 4 hours between 8AM and 8PM*)

```
$ crontab -l
0 8-20/4 * * * python3 /users/it/Documents/PLA.py
```

I gave the permission like this,

```
$ chmod a+x /users/it/Documents/PLA.py
```

tried the below options but didn't worked.

```
Last login: Mon Feb 10 09:50:19 on ttys000
it@Birgits-Mac-mini ~ % grep: /var/log/syslog: No such file or directory

it@Birgits-Mac-mini ~ % grep /users/it/Documents/PLA.py /var/log/syslog

grep: /var/log/syslog: No such file or directory

it@Birgits-Mac-mini ~ % grep PLA.py /var/log/syslog

grep: /var/log/syslog: No such file or directory
```

Below is the output from "ps aux",

```
it@Birgits-Mac-mini log % ps aux

USER               PID  %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND

it               95975  18.0  1.9  4965700 159384   ??  S     9:22AM   1:57.54 /Applications/Google

it               30974  12.6  0.9  4971292  72776   ??  Rs   Thu10AM 584:48.64 /System/Library/Pref

_windowserver      255   8.5  1.3  8230752 109480   ??  Ss   Wed10AM 1131:22.39 /System/Library/Priv

it               19795   5.1  0.8  4844620  66184   ??  R    Wed06PM  20:46.28 /Applications/Google

it               99157   4.9  1.2  8863704  99760   ??  S    10:30AM   0:02.09 /Applications/Google

it               99147   3.7  0.1  4369120   8164   ??  S    10:30AM   0:01.26 /users/it/Downloads/

it                 444   2.9  0.5  4955656  41144   ??  S    Wed10AM   0:19.42 /System/Applications

it               99148   2.0  1.0  4869212  80836   ??  S    10:30AM   0:01.97 /Applications/Google

it               95971   1.6  1.7  4894580 145260   ??  S     9:22AM   1:16.35 /Applications/Google

it                 441   1.0  2.6  5103024 215064   ??  S    Wed10AM  67:53.42 /Applications/Google

it                 439   0.9  2.5  8834628 207308   ??  S    Wed10AM 183:50.61 /usr/local/Cellar/py

it               97701   0.3  0.2  4313324  17488   ??  S     9:59AM   0:18.52 /usr/local/Cellar/py

root               120   0.3  0.1  4339764   6480   ??  Ss   Wed10AM  33:05.72 /usr/libexec/configd

root               145   0.2  0.1  4349816   8380   ??  Ss   Wed10AM   6:05.00 /usr/libexec/opendir

_hidd              168   0.2  0.1  4307956   6516   ??  Ss   Wed10AM   2:48.33 /usr/libexec/hidd

it               19796   0.1  0.4  4585596  33476   ??  S    Wed06PM  39:12.65 /Applications/Google

it               59040   0.1  2.5  5527404 206340   ??  S    Fri11AM 422:24.14 /Applications/Google

root               127   0.1  0.4  4425208  34904   ??  Ss   Wed10AM   4:24.95 /usr/libexec/logd

it               97693   0.0  0.2  8795096  18176   ??  S     9:59AM   0:00.14 /Applications/Google

it               97692   0.0  0.0  4335100   3184   ??  Ss    9:59AM   0:00.09 /System/Library/Fram

it               97691   0.0  0.0  4305576   2848   ??  Ss    9:59AM   0:00.03 /Applications/Google

it               97690   0.0  0.2  4551092  18352   ??  S     9:59AM   0:00.98 /Applications/Google

it               97689   0.0  0.3  4611760  22788   ??  S     9:59AM   0:00.63 /Applications/Google

it               97686   0.0  0.0  4308152   3028   ??  S     9:59AM   0:00.02 /Applications/Google

it               97684   0.0  0.7  4721700  59428   ??  S     9:59AM   0:03.86 /Applications/Google

_spotlight       97341   0.0  0.1  4312992   4752   ??  S     9:55AM   0:00.17 /System/Library/Fram

root             97138   0.0  0.0  4299092   3140   ??  S     9:50AM   0:13.74 /Applications/NordVP

it               97018   0.0  0.3  4326968  26720   ??  S     9:47AM   0:00.85 /System/Library/Fram

it               96778   0.0  0.3  4323256  24508   ??  S     9:36AM   0:01.55 /System/Library/Fram

it               96773   0.0  0.3  4323200  24380   ??  S     9:36AM   0:01.90 /System/Library/Fram

it               96767   0.0  0.3  4323332  23324   ??  S     9:36AM   0:01.39 /System/Library/Fram

it               95968   0.0  1.1  4829472  93256   ??  S     9:22AM   0:05.52 /Applications/Google

it               95739   0.0  0.4  4760068  34348   ??  S     9:19AM   0:00.37 /Applications/Google

it               95163   0.0  0.1  4349124  12392   ??  S     9:10AM   0:00.48 /usr/libexec/remindd

it               95159   0.0  0.2  4876828  16700   ??  Ss    9:10AM   0:00.81 /System/Applications

root             95156   0.0  0.1  4333564   4316   ??  Ss    9:10AM   0:00.09 /System/Library/Priv

it               95155   0.0  0.0  4296664   1508   ??  S     9:10AM   0:00.02 /System/Library/Fram

root             95150   0.0  0.0  4304952   2288   ??  Ss    9:10AM   0:00.05 /usr/libexec/colorsy

root             95128   0.0  0.0  4333184   2636   ??  Ss    9:01AM   0:01.76 /usr/sbin/ocspd

root             94993   0.0  0.0  4287868    124   ??  S     8:00AM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/cron

root             93354   0.0  0.0  4296060    124   ??  S     8:00PM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/cron

root             92833   0.0  0.0  4287868    124   ??  S     4:00PM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/cron

root             92815   0.0  0.2  4337888  15976   ??  Ss    3:45PM   0:07.49 /usr/libexec/PerfPow

root             92273   0.0  0.0  4287868    124   ??  S    12:00PM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/cron

root             91737   0.0  0.0  4287868    124   ??  S    Sun08AM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/cron

root             91623   0.0  0.1  4348312  11420   ??  Ss   Sun07AM   0:02.15 /System/Library/Priv

root             90078   0.0  0.0  4296060    124   ??  S    Sat08PM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/cron

root             89565   0.0  0.0  4287868    124   ??  S    Sat04PM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/cron

root             85959   0.0  0.1  4354056  10268   ??  Ss   Sat01PM   0:00.99 /System/Library/Priv

root             83751   0.0  0.0  4296060    124   ??  S    Sat12PM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/cron

root             81135   0.0  0.0  4305480   1636   ??  Ss   Sat10AM   0:00.06 /System/Library/Fram

root             81134   0.0  0.0  4307032   1780   ??  Ss   Sat10AM   0:00.05 /System/Library/Core

it               81128   0.0  0.0  4334996   2628   ??  S    Sat10AM   0:00.10 /System/Library/Fram

_ctkd            81126   0.0  0.0  4307032   1584   ??  Ss   Sat10AM   0:00.04 /System/Library/Fram

root             81125   0.0  0.2  4361812  16428   ??  Ss   Sat10AM   0:01.68 /System/Library/Core

root             81123   0.0  0.0  4335216   3200   ??  Ss   Sat10AM   0:00.16 /usr/libexec/wifivel

it               81122   0.0  0.0  4305064   2376   ??  S    Sat10AM   0:00.04 /usr/libexec/WiFiVel

root             81119   0.0  0.0  4335364   3056   ??  Ss   Sat10AM   0:00.11 /System/Library/Fram

root             81118   0.0  0.0  4305320   3160   ??  Ss   Sat10AM   0:00.04 /System/Library/Fram

root             81117   0.0  0.0  4306644   2172   ??  Ss   Sat10AM   0:00.07 /System/Library/Fram

root             81110   0.0  0.0  4335696   3020   ??  Ss   Sat10AM   0:00.36 /usr/libexec/secinit

root             81108   0.0  0.1  4333624   5204   ??  Ss   Sat10AM   0:00.07 /System/Library/Priv

it               81107   0.0  0.0  4305344   1080   ??  Ss   Sat10AM   0:00.03 /System/Library/Priv

root             81106   0.0  0.0  4333844   3540   ??  Ss   Sat10AM   0:00.22 /usr/libexec/pkd

root             81105   0.0  0.1  4356224  11544   ??  Ss   Sat10AM  10:10.82 /Applications/TeamVi

nobody           81104   0.0  0.1  4339212   5828   ??  Ss   Sat10AM   0:00.28 /System/Library/Core

root             81103   0.0  0.1  4348564   9780   ??  Ss   Sat10AM   0:00.72 /System/Library/Core

root             81102   0.0  0.1  4339124   6316   ??  Ss   Sat10AM   0:00.19 /usr/sbin/universala

root             81101   0.0  0.1  4333976   5588   ??  Ss   Sat10AM   0:00.32 /usr/libexec/UserEve

root             81100   0.0  0.1  4336772   5048   ??  Ss   Sat10AM   0:00.50 /System/Library/Fram

root             81096   0.0  0.1  4368928  10536   ??  Ss   Sat10AM   0:00.37 /System/Library/Core

root             78306   0.0  0.0  4278652    124   ??  S    Sat08AM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/cron

root             76350   0.0  0.0  4279488    280   ??  Ss   Sat03AM   0:00.01 /usr/sbin/aslmanager

it               74138   0.0  0.1  4360672   5484   ??  Ss   Fri10PM   0:00.17 /System/Library/Priv

it               74134   0.0  0.1  4306920   4396   ??  S    Fri10PM   0:00.42 /usr/libexec/silhoue

root             74130   0.0  0.0  4334868   3056   ??  Ss   Fri10PM   0:00.09 /usr/bin/sysdiagnose

it               74129   0.0  0.0  4336376   3792   ??  S    Fri10PM   0:00.67 /System/Library/Priv

root             73180   0.0  0.0  4287868    124   ??  S    Fri08PM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/cron

it               71614   0.0  0.9  4824004  74644   ??  S    Fri05PM   1:52.74 /Applications/Google

it               71595   0.0  0.0  4295848   2524   ??  Ss   Fri05PM   0:00.02 /System/Library/Fram

root             69453   0.0  0.0  4311088   3812   ??  Ss   Fri04PM   0:02.55 /System/Library/Priv

root             69451   0.0  0.0  4287868    124   ??  S    Fri04PM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/cron

it               68442   0.0  0.0  4839436   3656   ??  Ss   Fri03PM   0:00.08 /System/Library/Fram

it               68441   0.0  0.0  4823500   1348   ??  Ss   Fri03PM   0:00.09 /System/Library/Fram

root             68281   0.0  0.0  4279932    548   ??  Ss   Fri03PM   0:00.75 /usr/sbin/cron

root             68210   0.0  0.0  4813784   1328   ??  Ss   Fri03PM   0:00.03 /System/Library/Fram

it               68203   0.0  0.0  4333992   2776   ??  Ss   Fri03PM   0:00.07 /System/Library/Priv

it               62765   0.0  0.0  4840316   3804   ??  Ss   Fri12PM   0:00.10 /System/Library/Fram

it               62764   0.0  0.0  4823260   1352   ??  Ss   Fri12PM   0:00.04 /System/Library/Fram

root             62759   0.0  0.0  4307212   2484   ??  Ss   Fri12PM   0:00.09 /System/Library/Fram

root             62758   0.0  0.0  4338732   4164   ??  Ss   Fri12PM   0:00.25 /usr/sbin/systemsoun

postgres         59148   0.0  0.3  4489860  21572   ??  Ss   Fri11AM   3:41.18 postgres: postgres p

postgres         59058   0.0  0.1  4494228  12248   ??  Ss   Fri11AM  27:53.67 postgres: postgres p

root             57054   0.0  0.0  4333296   1864   ??  Ss   Fri10AM   0:00.10 /usr/libexec/microst

it               56797   0.0  2.8  5205180 239028   ??  S    Fri10AM  17:15.53 /Applications/Google

it               56796   0.0  0.5  4800904  45668   ??  S    Fri10AM   0:02.97 /Applications/Google

it               56787   0.0  1.3  4970324 111172   ??  S    Fri10AM   2:48.08 /Applications/Google

it               56387   0.0  0.2  4581824  13536   ??  S    Fri10AM   0:01.49 /Applications/Google

it               56254   0.0  0.0  4333992   2732   ??  Ss   Fri10AM   0:00.08 /System/Library/Priv

it               56252   0.0  0.0  4840420   3732   ??  Ss   Fri10AM   0:00.13 /System/Library/Fram

it               56251   0.0  0.0  4823500   1344   ??  Ss   Fri10AM   0:00.11 /System/Library/Fram

it               56248   0.0  0.1  4860548  11764   ??  Ss   Fri10AM   0:02.89 /System/Library/Fram

it               56246   0.0  0.3  4922680  24084   ??  Ss   Fri10AM   0:08.65 /System/Library/Fram

it               55891   0.0  0.0  4305584   2640   ??  Ss   Fri09AM   0:00.03 /Applications/Google

it               55861   0.0  0.1  4339036   4896   ??  S    Fri09AM   0:00.65 /System/Library/Fram

root             53191   0.0  0.0  4334784   2424   ??  Ss   Fri03AM   0:00.18 /System/Library/Priv

root             51877   0.0  0.0  4305440    320   ??  Ss   Fri12AM   0:00.24 aslmanager

it               50890   0.0  0.0  4304944   1700   ??  S    Thu11PM   0:00.45 /System/Library/Priv

root             50889   0.0  0.0  4306536   1144   ??  Ss   Thu11PM   0:00.05 /usr/libexec/mobilea

_fpsd            50239   0.0  0.0  4299432   1148   ??  Ss   Thu10PM   0:03.69 /System/Library/Priv

it               50087   0.0  0.1  4304840   7092   ??  S    Thu10PM   0:00.09 /System/Library/Core

it               50086   0.0  0.1  4406332   4580   ??  S    Thu10PM   0:00.87 /System/Library/Priv

it               49350   0.0  0.0  4304824   4084   ??  Ss   Thu09PM   0:00.04 /System/Library/Core

it               46281   0.0  0.1  4590996   8812   ??  S    Thu08PM   0:16.98 /System/Library/Fram

root             46229   0.0  0.0  4333964   3508   ??  Ss   Thu08PM   0:00.08 /usr/sbin/WirelessRa

it               40698   0.0  0.1  4340760   4564   ??  S    Thu06PM   0:03.12 /System/Library/Core

it               40477   0.0  0.0  4823472   1532   ??  Ss   Thu05PM   0:00.04 /System/Library/Fram

it               40450   0.0  0.0  4335100   3000   ??  Ss   Thu05PM   0:00.15 /System/Library/Fram

it               40448   0.0  0.5  8846432  43372   ??  S    Thu05PM   3:51.83 /Applications/Google

it               40446   0.0  0.2  4549324  17832   ??  S    Thu05PM   0:01.86 /Applications/Google

it               40445   0.0  0.2  4565640  16416   ??  S    Thu05PM   0:01.39 /Applications/Google

it               40442   0.0  0.3  4653872  25992   ??  S    Thu05PM   0:29.55 /Applications/Google

it               39821   0.0  0.0  4839436   3652   ??  Ss   Thu05PM   0:00.08 /System/Library/Fram

it               39820   0.0  0.0  4823500   1344   ??  Ss   Thu05PM   0:00.09 /System/Library/Fram

it               37243   0.0  1.3  4970212 107340   ??  S    Thu03PM 162:03.76 /Users/it/Desktop/pg

_assetcache      33411   0.0  0.1  4337684   4996   ??  Ss   Thu01PM   0:02.48 /System/Library/Priv

root             30983   0.0  0.1  4846008   4236   ??  Ss   Thu10AM   0:00.60 /System/Library/Fram

it               30982   0.0  0.3  4362412  24016   ??  Ss   Thu10AM 2121:48.95 /System/Library/Fram

it               30981   0.0  0.1  4842656   4704   ??  Ss   Thu10AM   0:01.04 /System/Library/Fram

it               30980   0.0  0.0  4827816   1356   ??  Ss   Thu10AM   0:00.47 /System/Library/Fram

it               30979   0.0  0.1  4341464  11412   ??  Ss   Thu10AM   0:01.82 /System/Library/Fram

it               30978   0.0  0.1  4861480  11824   ??  Ss   Thu10AM   0:03.65 /System/Library/Fram

it               30977   0.0  0.1  4861480  11984   ??  Ss   Thu10AM   0:03.55 /System/Library/Fram

it               30976   0.0  0.1  4861484  11780   ??  Ss   Thu10AM   0:03.72 /System/Library/Fram

it               30973   0.0  0.0  4839520   3772   ??  Ss   Thu10AM   0:00.07 /System/Library/Fram

it               30971   0.0  0.0  4840236   3724   ??  Ss   Thu10AM   0:00.23 /System/Library/Fram

it               30970   0.0  0.0  4827848   1356   ??  Ss   Thu10AM   0:00.25 /System/Library/Fram

it               30969   0.0  0.0  4337836   4020   ??  Ss   Thu10AM   0:00.35 /System/Library/Fram

it               30967   0.0  0.4  4964760  36496   ??  Ss   Thu10AM   0:09.21 /System/Library/Pref

it               30964   0.0  0.3  4891768  24516   ??  Ss   Thu10AM   0:05.03 /System/Library/Pref

it               30956   0.0  0.3  4913528  21144   ??  S    Thu10AM   0:04.77 /System/Applications

it               30664   0.0  0.0  4344692   3976   ??  Ss   Thu10AM   0:28.52 /System/Library/Fram

root <span class="gmail-Apple-conver

...
```

Can anyone please help me to find what is the exact issue and whether i have missed anything.

**Note:** if i take command prompt and run "python3 PLA.py" it is running fine.

Comment: Try this: * 8-20/4 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /users/it/Documents/PLA.py >> ~/cron.log 2>&1

Comment: i read somewhere that by default, cron logging is disabled, try command `mail` or look at /var/mail/<username>

Comment: @MichaelK i entered this * 8-20/4 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /users/it/Documents/PLA.py >> ~/cron.log 2>&1  but nothing happened or changed? What is this command?

Comment: @warungmanChecked but not found anthing